# Multicolumn textarea area to insert into SharePoint 2007 but display not correctly

Tags: 2007, spservices, textarea

I have a form that uses SPServices and have a textarea field for the user to insert multi rows data.

The data from the textarea can be successfully inserted into the SharePoint 2007 column of type 'Multiple lines of text' as shown below

[image]

However, when I edit the item, it seems that the "multi-lines" have become a single line. (It display all the text inside from the textarea field as a single line and not exactly what is written on the textarea.)

Any Insight?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you escape the Rich Text that you send into the Web Service call. For example, HTML tags should look like

```
&lt;table&gt;
```

rather than

```
<table>
```

Comment: Hi Marc, how do I pass the textarea field as a Rich Text into Web Service Call? Would a JQuery Rich Text field (such as those listed in http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors) help? (cause I was wondering if SPServices can take the values from a JQuery rich text field.)

Comment: I tried using one of the JQuery Rich Text and notice that this time, I am able to retrieve the Rich text in SharePoint 2007, but I was not able to insert any text into the SharePoint 2007. Any insight?

Comment: I just realized that the formatting was wrong on my initial answer. Does that help?

Comment: Hi Marc, it does not help cause right now, I see lots of gubbish content in my fields in SharePoint 2007 List.

Comment: What does the "gubbish" content look like?